# How do I put these objects in a array to create a constant flow?

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm trying to make a helicopter game in javascript. Though atm I have one airplane flying from right to left.
How do I make the array, so I get a constant flow of airplanes (a difference of +-200 spaces on x).

Here is the code that I have atm to add airplanes and I simply don't know how to add the array to it to add different airplanes.

```
var airplane = new Image();
airplane.src = "images/airplane.png";
var posX = 700;
var posY;
var bmpAirplane;

function init() {
    loader.onComplete = handleComplete;
}

function handleComplete() {
    displayAirplane();  

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
}

function displayAirplane () { 
        posY = Math.floor((Math.random()*270)+10);
        bmpAirplane = new createjs.Bitmap(airplane);
        bmpAirplane.x = posX;
        bmpAirplane.y = posY;

        stage.addChild(bmpAirplane);
        stage.update();
}


function tick()
{               
    bmpAirplane.x -=10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming "displayAirplane" method is what creates the airplanes. It looks like "bmpAirplane" is holding the reference to your current airplane. Turn this into an array which will be used to hold many airplanes. Then in your tick() method, loop through this array, updating each airplane object inside it by the airplane speed.